# Setting Accept Headers in PyGithub API for getting commit diff

Tags: github-api, pygithub, github-api-v3

I want to get the result of the below query using PyGithub. Is there a way to set accept header in pygithub? I want the output in diff format and I don't want to use github compare API.

So is there a way to make below request using pygithub?

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.diff" \
  http(s)://{hostname}/api/v3/repos/octocat/hello-world/commits/REF
```